# Creating Linked Server Object to same instance

Tags: sql-server-2014, linked-server, sql-server-express

I'm trying to create a Linked Server Object back to the same SQL Express 2014 server instance (see below for the context), but I'm hitting the following error...

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "NewServer".
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "NewServer" returned message "Invalid connection string attribute". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

I've used the following configuration...

- Linked Server: `NewServer`
- Server Type: `Other data source`
- Provider: `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server`
- Product name: `{empty}`
- Data source: `LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS` (have also tried actual server name)
- Provider string: `SQLNCLI`
- Security, Login: `Using the login's current security context` (have also tried `using this security context` and providing `sa/password`)

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?

Is it because I'm trying to create a linked server object back to itself?

---

For context, the reason I'm doing this is due to a client who's UAT and Production environments have a linked server with which we need to interact.

As a result I need to create stored procedures on my local development machine that use the `[NewServer].[Database].[dbo].[Table]` name... so that the sproc can be stored in the repo and easily deployed via comparison tools.  But it won't let me create/update the sprocs without the valid data source.

I thought the simple solution would be to create the `[Database].[dbo].[Table]` on my local SQL Express 2014 instance and add a linked server back to itself using the `[NewServer]` name.

Is the only option to create a new SQL instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already worked it out...

The problem was incorrectly setting the provider string to `SQLNCLI`.

When I removed it (leaving it empty) it connected immediately...

- Linked Server: `NewServer`
- Server Type: `Other data source`
- Provider: `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server`
- Product name: `{empty}`
- Data source: `LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS`
- Provider string: `{empty}` **(UPDATED)**
- Security, Login: `Using the login's current security context`